# Почему при просмотре товара, "хлебные крошки" ведут на совершенно другую родительскую категорию?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, yoast

Есть сайт на вордпрессе (+woocommerce +yoast seo)
На этом сайте, есть категория продуктов
https://evroflag24.ru/category-product/souvenirs/podarochnye-nabory-novogodnie-s-logotipom
Но почему-то при просмотре товара из этой категории, видны хлебные крошки, в которых указана соверенно другая родительская категория.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как на этом сайте, правильно настроить "хлебные крошки" и в чём ошибка?

p.s.
Это связано с плагином Yoast
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Yoast можно задать "главную" категорию для товара.